# Open GL Create 4 Views Like 3ds max or maya

Tags: c++, opengl

How can I Create a 4 views (LEFT/TOP/PERSPECTIVE/FRONT) in Open GL ??

I Have Used this :

```
int main(int c,char ** argv)
{
    glutInit(&c,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE |GLUT_DEPTH |GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowSize(w,h);
    MainWin =glutCreateWindow("Teapot Window");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    LeftWin = glutCreateSubWindow(MainWin,0,0,s_window_w,s_window_h);
    glutDisplayFunc(displayLeft);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshapeLeft);

    TopWin = glutCreateSubWindow(MainWin,s_window_w+3,0,s_window_w,s_window_h);
    glutDisplayFunc(displayTop);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshapeTop);

    PerspectiveWin = glutCreateSubWindow(MainWin,0,s_window_h+3,s_window_w,s_window_h);
    glutDisplayFunc(displayPerspective);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshapePerspective);

    FrontWin = glutCreateSubWindow(MainWin,s_window_w+3,s_window_h+3,s_window_w,s_window_h);
    glutDisplayFunc(displayFront);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshapeFront);



    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Then I have make the projection for top and left and like this :

```
glViewport(0,0,w,h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-0.5f,0.5f,-0.35f,0.35f,1,500);
```

When I use the top lines for the front also , the output is something like this  :
[image]

Where is my fault ? 
thanks in advance

Why the Front view is empty and the perspective and left view are same ??
For perspective projection i had used glFrustum ....
So Am I going wrong ? 
Please help on creating multiple views like 3ds  max or maya ...
below is the code for display functions:

```
void displayLeft()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,light_pos);

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.2f,0.3f,0.4f,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glTranslatef(teapot_x,teapot_y,teapot_z);
    glRotatef(teapot_angle,0,1,0);
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    glutSolidTeapot(0.2f);

    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void displayTop()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,light_pos);

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.2f,0.3f,0.4f,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glTranslatef(teapot_x,teapot_y,teapot_z);
    glRotatef(teapot_angle,0,1,0);
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    glutSolidTeapot(0.2f);

    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void displayFront()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,light_pos);

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.2f,0.3f,0.4f,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glTranslatef(teapot_x,teapot_y,teapot_z);
    glRotatef(teapot_angle,0,1,0);
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    glutSolidTeapot(0.2f);

    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void displayPerspective()
{

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,light_pos);

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.2f,0.3f,0.4f,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glTranslatef(teapot_x,teapot_y,teapot_z);
    glRotatef(0,0,1,0);
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    glutSolidTeapot(0.2f);

    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Please include all the relevant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `glViewport` and `glScissor` to cut out panes of the window. Then for each pane perform the rendering as usual. Setting the projection matrix is actually a drawing state operation, so it belongs into the display function, not reshape.

Your display function should become something like

```
void ViewportScissor(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(x, y, width, height);
    glScissor(x, y, width, height);
}

void display(void)
{

    int const win_width  = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    int const win_height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR);
    glClear(…);

    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR);

    ViewportScissor(0, 0, win_width/2, win_height/2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    setup_frontview_projection();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    setup_frontview();
    draw_scene();

    ViewportScissor(win_width/2, 0, win_width/2, win_height/2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    setup_rightview_projection();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    setup_rightview();
    draw_scene();

    ViewportScissor(0, win_height/2, win_width/2, win_height/2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    setup_topview_projection();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    setup_topview();
    draw_scene();

    ViewportScissor(win_width/2, win_height/2, win_width/2, win_height/2);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    setup_freecamview_projection();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    setup_freecamview();
    draw_scene();

    glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

Adding splitter lines/frames is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: for front view , should I use rotatef(90,0,1,0) , before using LookAt function ?

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid: No, the view direction should be implemented as parameter to LookAt. If you use LookAt at all, because just specifying x,y,z offsets and spans in a ortho projection makes more sense.